# Doxygen (1.8.8) putting C++ constructors / public member functions on group page rather than class page

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am trying to document some of my code with Doxygen. I have a library which I'm calling a Doxygen group, and many classes in separate header files. A number of the constructors are shown as public member functions on the class pages, but their documentation is shown on the group page rather than in the Constructors && Destructors section on the class page. Some are not; I haven't exactly figured out the pattern yet.

Here is one that fails:

```
/**
 * @addtogroup gr_espresso
 * @{
 */

/**
 * @file ToyTagger.hh
 */
...
namespace Espresso {
  ...
  /**
   * @class ToyTagger
   * @brief Fake tagging algorithm
   * @details ...
   *
   */
  class ToyTagger {
  public:

    /**
     * @brief Simple constructor.
     * @details ...
     */
    ToyTagger(CalibrationMode _mode, const Distribution& _pdf, const Calibration* _smear_cal = nullptr);
    ...
  }
}
/**
 * @}
 */
```

The following documentation is produced for the class ToyTagger:

[image]

The constructor shown above in pseudocode is listed under Public Member Functions, but not under Constructors & Destructor documentation. Instead, the "More info" link leads to the page for the group gr_espresso. The same thing is true for another constructor, and also for one of the three member functions:

[image]

I haven't shown the code for the second constructor or three member functions, but there is no apparent difference.

On the other hand, here is one that succeeds:

```
/**
 * @addtogroup gr_espresso
 * @{
 */

/**
 * @file StandardCalibration.hh
 */
...
namespace Espresso
{
  ...
  class StandardCalibration : public Calibration {
  public:
   /**
    * @brief Default constructor
    * @details Simple constructor that creates a trivial calibration
    * where \f$\omega(\eta) = \eta\f$
    */
    StandardCalibration();
    ...
  }
}

/**
 * @}
 */
```

This generates the documentation I would expect:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here? Am I doing something wrong that leads to such (apparently) unpredictable behavior?

Comment: One difference I see is that you use in the second example a default constructor whereas in the first exmple a specialized constructor is used.

Comment: @gmug That's a good observation. I'll look through other constructors in the library and see if they follow the same pattern. This wouldn't explain why the two member functions returning void are documented on this page and not the first, but maybe that's a separate issue.

Comment: Sadly, I've found other examples in my library where the constructor takes arguments and is properly documented.

Comment: Blind shot: is your constructor the first member after the `public:` ?

Comment: @Thomas, yes, one of them is.

Comment: could you provide the whole .h file?

Comment: @Thomas I've edited the question to include the whole header file.

Comment: Did you consider an update of doxygen? On which OS are you? And what happen if you add just after `public:` a default constructor?

Comment: @Thomas I upgraded to 1.8.10 with no change. I also added a default constructor -- the documentation for this default constructor appears as expected. However, the other two are still broken.

Comment: Given your email address I bet you can't share the whole project, could you produce an [mcve]?

Comment: @Thomas I'll work on this, thanks again.

Comment: Running Doxygen 1.8.7 (configured with Doxywizard default settings except disabling LaTeX and diagrams) on just `ToyTagger.hh` produced the correct result for me. The constructors are listed as "Public functions" in the overview at the top, but under "Constructors & Destructors" for the details. The "More..." link jumps to the correct spot, not to the group page. Can you run doxygen on an individual file as well? Maybe any of the included files in ToyTagger.hh has some broken doxygen code? Are there any warnings during doxygen generation?

Comment: @JohannesS. I am noticing this now as I try to make a minimal working example as Thomas suggested; it's pretty hard to reproduce the error I am seeing. I will look over the warning messages.

Comment: @Thomas, and Johannes - At first my MWE did not suffer from this problem. In trying to create a MWE I discovered the issue. I was adding the corresponding .cpp file to the Doxygen group as well, and getting rid of this fixes the issue. I figured this out with both of your help. If you make answers like "Making a MWE could narrow down the issue" for Thomas and "A single .hh file might look fine but you must consider interactions between multiple files when debugging oxygen" for Johannes, I would give bounties to those.

Comment: Done. Feel free to add informations to the answer to make it more complete

Answer (score 1):

You should try to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to track the issue.

Also, try to check what file you add to which group: it may leads to weird behavior sometimes...