# Doxygen class and function in a same member group

Tags: c++, doxygen

Can a class be put into a member group like a function? For example,

```
/** Some module.
 *
 *  @defgroup Group
 *  @{
 */

/** @name Same utility
 *
 */
/** @{*/

/** Class A.
 *
 */
class A
{
};

/** Function.
 *
 */
void f();

/** @}*/ // end Same utility


/** Class B.
 *
 */
class B
{
};

/** @}*/ // end Group
```

The above code will put `f()` into a custom section called "Same utility", but the document for class `A` is still in the section "class" with class `B`. So is there a way to group the class `A` into a member group as well?

Comment: May be this question is similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529466/doxygen-1-8-8-putting-c-constructors-public-member-functions-on-group-page